# Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a table in mongo with the following structure:

```
array(
    'Subscriber' => array(
         '0' => 'Name 1',
         '1' => 'Name 1',
         '2' => 'Name 2',
    )
)
```

I am using the following code to remove an item from subscriber:

```
$setData["subscriber.1"]=1;
$result = $this->mongo->pages->update($condition1, array('$unset' => $setData), array('safe' => true));
$result = $this->mongo->pages->update($condition1, array('$pull' => array('subscriber' => null)), array('safe' => true));
```

It works fine but gives `Mongo cursor Error:Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array`

Anyone know why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did used single quotes (''). PHP will ignore the variables which are within single quotes. You have to remove the single quotes or replace them by double quotes.

This should work:

```
$setData["subscriber.1"]=1;
$result = $this->mongo->pages->update($condition1, array($unset => $setData), array('safe' => true));
$result = $this->mongo->pages->update($condition1, array($pull => array('Pinned' => null)), array('safe' => true));
```

Comment: This is a mongodb question, the single quotes are actually correct

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that it is because of:

```
$result = $this->mongo->pages->update($condition1, array('$pull' => array('Pinned' => null)), array('safe' => true));
```

You have no `Pinned` in your document and it most definitely is not an array.

That is essentially what this error says: `Pinned` is not an array.

Comment: I put a little on the question it is not pinned, it is subscribed. I have fixed the question. Please see it again. My apologies.

Comment: @user1795109 I will be very surprised if the answer above mine works, that means that you set the key of your operations array to a variable.